# ng not recognized after installing angular CLI

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, angular-cli

when I am trying to install angular CLI in my computer with Windows 10 64 bit OS, it always ended up like as seen in the screenshot:

[image]

after installing it and try to check the version using 'ng -v', I get message:

'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I also noticed that there are files that are not included in the installation not like the one in the tutorial that I'm following in this link:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular4/angular4_environment_setup.htm

I also tried searching for possible solution on this but unfortunate to find one. have somebody experienced this too and found solution?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you may not have the right version **installed globally**. Run:

```
> npm ls -g --depth=0
C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @angular/cli@6.0.0
+-- firebase-tools@3.17.7
+-- npm-check-updates@2.14.2
+-- npm-windows-upgrade@4.1.0
+-- vsts-npm-auth@0.31.2
`-- webpack-bundle-analyzer@2.11.1
```

If you don't see the latest version, you have to install the new version globally with:

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

You might have to do this as well to remove the old version:

```
npm r -g angular-cli
```

Comment: I also tried the npm ls -g --depth=0 but it only has @angular/cli@6.0.0 in the list.

Answer (score 0):

For an unknown reason the path setting is messed up, go to control panel and edit path setting in the environment variables

C:\Users{windows-user-id}\AppData\Roaming\npm